# How can I add weight on an order confirmation?

Tags: magento2, email

I would like to add the total cart weight onto the order confirmation. On Magento 1 this code was added-

```
<td colspan="4" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
            <strong><?php echo $this->__('Total UPS Weight:'); ?></strong><?php echo " " . $_order->getWeight(); ?>
        </td>
```

So it looked like-

```
 <?php $i=0; foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $_item): ?>
<?php if($_item->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++; ?>
<tbody<?php echo $i%2 ? ' bgcolor="#F6F6F6"' : '' ?>>
    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
</tbody>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<tbody>
   <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
            <strong><?php echo $this->__('Total UPS Weight:'); ?></strong><?php echo " " . $_order->getWeight(); ?>
        </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>

<tbody>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
</tbody>
```

On the email/items.phtml file and it worked great. The same code in Magento 2 does not work. I added the code to current Magento 2 code so it looks like-

```
<?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
        <?php if (!$_item->getParentItem()) : ?>
            <tbody>
                <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
            <strong><?php echo $this->__('Total UPS Weight:'); ?></strong><?php echo " " . $_order->getWeight(); ?>
        </td>
   </tr>
            </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I get the order confirmation it just says-

Error filtering template: Invalid method Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items::__

Comment: tjjen, did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the below file:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml

to your theme location like below:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml

And use the below code for your **items.phtml**:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order): ?>
    <?php $_items = $_order->getAllItems(); ?>
    <table class="email-items">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items') ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-qty">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty') ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-price">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Price') ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php $totalWeight = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php if (!$_item->getParentItem()) : ?>
                <tbody>
                    <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                </tbody>
                <?php $totalWeight += $_item->getWeight()*$_item->getQtyOrdered() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
                    <strong><?php echo __('Total UPS Weight:'); ?> </strong><?= $totalWeight ?>
                </td>
           </tr>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot class="order-totals">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore()) && $_order->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
        <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
        <?php if ($_giftMessage): ?>
            <br />
            <table class="message-gift">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message for this Order') ?></h3>
                        <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                        <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It gets me closer. The only problem I currently have is that it doesn't take quantity into consideration. So if I have 2 the weight on the item needs to be double. Any ideas? Thanks for the help on this.

Comment: Can you check the updated answer?

Comment: I added a few items to test and all I get on the confirmation is Total UPS Weight: 0

Comment: Can you sales_order_item table if it stores the weight correctly or not? Also check of the products have correct weight or not? I have edited my answer. Can you please check.

Comment: I believe it store the weight correctly, I get all of my shipping rates just fine and your first attempt worked well just not with quantity. I tried the most recent code and it pulled up the 0 for weight again.

Comment: Can you check it now. It should work now. I have check it an diya working fine now. I have changes OrderedQty to QtyOrdered

Comment: You welcome :) Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to modify 2 files if you want to add a column to item detail named Weight.

1: **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml**

Overwrite this file:

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="item-info">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items') ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-qty">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty') ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-price">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Price') ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-weight">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Weight') ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

2: **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml:39**
** if item is_virtual weight will be return 0**

```
<td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?></td>
<td class="item-price">
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
</td>
<td class="item-weight">
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getWeight(); /**/ ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy `items.phtml` from

> {Magento2Root}/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml

Add new `th` just after `price`

```
<th class="item-weight">
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Total UPS Weight:') ?>
</th>
```

Above code will add a new heading to table, Now we need to render `weight` in `td` for each ordered item row.

For that we need to copy

> {Magento2Root}/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

to

> {Magento2Root}/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

Add below code after `td class="item-price"`

```
<?php if (!$_item->getParentItem()) { ?>
    <td class="item-weight">
        <?php $totalWeight += $_item->getWeight() * $_item->getOrderedQty()* 1  ?>
    </td>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope above will help!